# Why system.runAs(currentUser) is solving mixed DML?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I wrote a test class. In test setup  i am creating permissionSet and other custom object data. 
my test method would be like below,

```
testdata()
{
  user = new user(values)
  System.runAs(user)
  {
     insert permisisonset(...value...);
  }
   insert customObject_c(..values...);
}
testmethod()
{
     createdata();
     permissionHandler.updatePermisionSet(); //Initially I got mixed DML error here. but above runaA(user) help me solved.
}
```

i checked the log. Its pointing to the original class (insert permissionsetList) mixed DML error. After that i added another runas in test method like below,

```
testmethod()
{
  createData();
  System.runAs(new User(ID = UserInfo.getUserID()))
    {
         permissionHandler.updatePermisionSet(); //working fine.
    }
}
```

Its working. I am confused.. still its running in system context then why it got resolved by adding getUserID() in runAs context.

Any advise or comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question: you're using `System.RunAs()` to run exactly as *the same user as before*, right?

[This](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm) documentation has some interesting information. After explaining the cause of the error, it says this (highlight is mine):

> This restriction exists because *some sObjects affect the user’s access to records in the org*. You must insert or update these types of sObjects in a different transaction to prevent operations from happening with incorrect access-level permissions.

From the `System.RunAs()`[documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm), we know that:

> The system method runAs enables you to write test methods that change the user context to an existing user or a new user

and that:

> The original system context is started again after all runAs test methods complete.

I'm assuming that, the moment you do `System.Runas(User u)`, all the permissions of the user `u` are re-read form the database and re-applied to the running context. I guess that would be the reason why it works. But it's just an educated guess. Unfortunately, I don't have any further documentation to support that idea.

Interestingly enough, the both links above mentions using `System.RunAs()` as a workaround for the mixed DML error.

Comment: [Using the runAs Method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm) goes in further detail; you might consider adding this to your answer.

Comment: The use of `system.runAs` ***creates a new transaction***.