# No query results in System.runAs after inserting records by the same user

Tags: soql, unit-test, visibility, runas

The issue I am having is that after creating records within the System.runAs block, the user creating these records cannot see them.

```
@TestSetup
static void setupData() {
  User regularUser = new DataFactory.UserCreation()
    .setFirstName('Regular Test')
    .setProfile('Custom Profile')
    .create();
}

@IsTest
static void testMethod() {
  User regularUser = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE FirstName = 'Regular Test' LIMIT 1];

  Test.startTest();
  List<WorkOrder> woList = new List<WorkOrder>();
  System.runAs(regularUser) {
    WorkOrder wo1 = new DataFactory.WorkOrderCreation()
      .setStatus('New')
      .create();
    System.debug(wo1); // Looks good and the Id field is populated
    woList = [SELECT Id FROM WorkOrder];
    System.debug(woList); // Empty
    System.debug(woList.size()); // 0
  }
  woList = [SELECT Id FROM WorkOrder];
  System.debug(woList.size()); // 1
  System.debug(woList[0]); // Looks good
  Test.stopTest();
}
```

This is the gist of it. Why can't I possibly query the records as a user who is the owner of those records?

Edit

-Tried removing `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()`

What I checked **outside** the `System.runAs` block:

-Details of the UserRecordAccess object records related to created WorkOrder records:

```
UserRecordAccess uRecAccess = [SELECT RecordId, MaxAccessLevel FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId = :regularUser.Id AND RecordId = :woList[0].Id];
System.debug(uRecAccess.RecordId); // Same id as in wo1 debug
System.debug(uRecAccess.MaxAccessLevel); // 'All'
```

-Ownership/creation details on the WorkOrder records:

```
List<WorkOrder> woList = [SELECT Owner.Name, CreatedBy.Name FROM WorkOrder];
System.debug(woList.size()); // 1
System.debug(woList[0]); // 'Regular Test' on both fields
```

-Tried running the query in a second `System.runAs`

-Tried moving WO creation into the `setupData()` and querying from the `testMethod()`

Nothing worked so far

Comment: Does your data factory actually insert the created record in the database (does it do a DML in the `create` method), or just provide an in-memory record?

Comment: @PhilW it does indeed insert the record, then returns what was inserted. If that wasn't the case I wouldn't get any results in woList outside the System.runAs block either.

Comment: Maybe verify after insertion the Owner is actually the creating user? E.g. does a trigger change the Owner depending on the location?

Comment: Just gonna summarize what I checked because formatting in the comments seems scuffed - After `System.runAs` block, I checked `UserRecordAccess` object records where `UserId` = `regularUser.Id` + `RecordId` = `woList[0].Id` and the field `MaxAccessLevel` shows 'All' value.  

Then checked `Owner.Name` and `CreatedBy.Name` fields on the created records and both show 'Regular Test' value.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to add the above details, and any other contextual information (such as your debug output etc.) that might be useful? Cheers

Comment: @PhilW Done, will try to keep editing it to include relevant information.

Comment: What permissions does the `Custom Profile` include for the relevant objects (I assume you're relying on profile permissions instead of the modern permission set approach since the code doesn't appear to include any perm set assignments)? Then again I wouldn't expect this to have a direct impact since you're not using the new SOQL USER_MODE feature...

Comment: `Custom Profile` has Read/Edit permissions for the `WorkOrder` object. As you mentioned though, it shouldn't matter in this case.

Comment: Maybe remove `Test.startTest();` and `Test.stopTest();` or make sure your query is after `stopTest()`? If you do a second time `System.runAs(regularUser) {...}` in the end of your test and query then, does the test user see the record?

Comment: @FelixvanHove Unfortunately not. Still cannot query created records in either of the scenarios you mentioned.

Comment: What it looks like, and what one remark on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/153184/why-system-runascurrentuser-is-solving-mixed-dml also supports: the use of system.runAs creates a new transaction. It looks like the commit of the insert to the database is only done when the runAs block is closed. So inside the runAs block, no changes seem to be happening to the database, but outside of it, they are visible. Unfortunately, runAs is poorly documented.

Comment: @SanderdeJong I moved the creation of WO records into the `setupData()`, then tried querying from the `testMethod()` inside a `System.runAs` block - something I've done before and didn't run into any issues but still no luck here for some reason.